# Problem deploying node app on Heroku – build successful, but returns Error: Cannot find module 'request'

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I´m still experimenting with node and this modern architecture with javascript, react and so on. But I have a lot of experience with web development (PHP, ASP.NET).
Anyway, I´m working on transcoding of my old frameworks to node and trying out Heroku to host it. At the beginning stages, I had managed to deploy and make my application run completely in the web to test it out. Then, I started to work on many other parts from my application and never tested the deploy again, until now.

I already searched the full day to debug the problems that were occurring and managed to get to a point where the build in Heroku is successful. The problem is that when I run the access the address where was supposed to work, it returns me a generic error:

at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/system" host=syncsystem-multiplatform-v1.herokuapp.com request_id=9c7e251e-4947-45cb-928e-674148718045 fwd="186.231.136.56" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http

And in the “view logs” section, this is what is displayed:

```
    2021-04-14T21:05:29.722072+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2021-04-14T21:05:38.899481+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app`
    2021-04-14T21:05:46.776113+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
    2021-04-14T21:05:46.851815+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2021-04-14T21:05:46.551799+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626
    2021-04-14T21:05:46.551865+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
    2021-04-14T21:05:46.551866+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^
    2021-04-14T21:05:46.551866+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2021-04-14T21:05:46.551866+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'request'
    2021-04-14T21:05:46.551867+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
    2021-04-14T21:05:46.551867+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/app.js
    2021-04-14T21:05:46.551872+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:623:15)
    2021-04-14T21:05:46.551872+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:527:27)
    2021-04-14T21:05:46.551877+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:681:19)
    2021-04-14T21:05:46.551878+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    2021-04-14T21:05:46.551878+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:20:17)
    2021-04-14T21:05:46.551878+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:30)
    2021-04-14T21:05:46.551879+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:10)
    2021-04-14T21:05:46.551879+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:641:32)
    2021-04-14T21:05:46.551879+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    2021-04-14T21:05:46.551879+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:837:10) {
    2021-04-14T21:05:46.551884+00:00 app[web.1]:   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
    2021-04-14T21:05:46.551885+00:00 app[web.1]:   requireStack: [ '/app/app.js' ]
    2021-04-14T21:05:46.551885+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

During the research I did to debug, I found these main points:
1 - In my Procfile, I´ve got this line:
web: node app

2 - On my package. Json, I understand that this part is essential:

```
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node app"
    },
```

3 – On my main app.js, I´ve got the configuration done with Heroku´s server variables:

```
    app.listen(process.env.PORT || process.env.CONFIG_SYSTEM_PORT, ()=>{
        if(gSystemConfig.configDebug === true)
        {
            console.log(`app running on port: ${ process.env.PORT || process.env.CONFIG_SYSTEM_PORT }`);
        }
    });
```

4 – I´ve disabled cache on server variables by Heroku´s app settings:
NODEMODULESCACHE=false

5 – I´ve set up a linked github repository to make the deploy automatic:
https://github.com/jorge-mauricio/syncsystem-multiplatformv1-dev/tree/master

If anyone needs to take a look at the full source code, it´s on a github repository:
https://github.com/jorge-mauricio/syncsystem-multiplatformv1-dev/tree/master

There are some react folders in it, but that´s not the main focus now. The main focus is to run the application in node (app.js, backend_node, components_node), which, by the way, is running perfectly on the local environment.

The online address where is supposed to load a login screen, is at:
http://syncsystem-multiplatform-v1.herokuapp.com/system

Anyone has any ideas of what I could be missing out?

Thanks,
Jorge Mauricio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks the problem is exactly what the output error says: it cannot find the module `request`. In your file `package.json`, you specify the libraries (modules) you're using, and `request` seems to be missing from there.

When you do for example `npm install express` (or `yarn add express`, same thing), you add this library to your `package.json` file. Heroku starts by getting these dependencies from `package.json`, so that they then can be required.

Also, from the looks of it, [the request library has been deprecated](https://github.com/request/request). I would suggest switching to [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) which seems to fulfill the same needs.

EDIT: I see now that the module is actually listed in `package-lock.json`, so there shouldn't be a problem with it. However, you can try running `npm install request` to add it manually, then deploying to Heroku. That way, you can see if the problem seems to lie with Heroku configs or with the module itself.

Comment: Thanks Emil. Just to clarify: so there are some modules that I don´t need to install manually, when I´m running my app locally, but I should install and specify in the package.json?

Comment: Wow! Worked! Thanks a million!

Comment: I jumped the gun a bit and said it was missing, before I found it in `package-lock.json`. Heroku _should_ find it there as well, but the question is why it doesn't. My suggestion was to install it via `npm install request` to see if the error would go away

Comment: @JorgeMauricio Awesome, glad to hear it :)